# How to git fetch from a central remote repository?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I'm new to Git and I'm a little confused how to use "git fetch"

I have a central repository that I access using SSH, I have created a repository using git clone, just like this:

```
$ cd /my/local/repotest
$ git clone ssh://andre@somedomain.com/var/github/repotest .
```

Now other developer have pushed some new files to the central repo in "somedomain.com"

My question is, how can I fetch the new files and changes via command line?

Comment: http://gitref.org/remotes/#fetch 
You should read gitref.org. All basic commands n usage is given there nicely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a another repository you need to define some "remotes".  You add them to your **.git/config** file like so:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://server.hostname.com/home/me/git/myrepo
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Once your cloned repo has these, you can *push* or *pull* changes like so:

```
git pull origin 
git push origin
```

See also **git help remote** and **git help pull**. I also find [github's help pages](http://help.github.com/remotes/) quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git fetch` or `git pull` from within your local tree.

`git pull` is shorthand for performing a 'git fetch' followed by a 'git merge'. For more information on the difference between fetch and pull, check out the following: [What's the difference between git pull and git fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` in this case. `git pull` does a `git fetch` from the repo and "updates" ( merge in the first form, rebase in the `--rebase form`) your working directory as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is possible also to pull only the new files? I'm using git to pull the files from a central repository to a production environment, but I don't want to change the files in my local repo. This is possible?